# Opscenter does not show my key spaces

Tags: datastax-enterprise, opscenter

In my opscenter web page, in the schema tab I was unable to see any of my keyspaces(0 Keyspaces  |  0 Column Families ) and in the logs keep on saying

```
WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,373 42937 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,373 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,373 42938 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,373 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,373 42939 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,373 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,374 42940 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,374 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,374 42941 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,374 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,374 42942 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,374 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,374 42943 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,374 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,374 42944 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,374 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,374 42945 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,374 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,374 42946 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,374 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,374 42947 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,375 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,375 42948 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,375 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,375 42949 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,375 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,375 42950 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,375 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,375 42951 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,375 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,375 42952 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,375 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,375 42953 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,375 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,375 42954 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,375 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,376 42955 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,376 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,376 42956 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,376 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-18 20:02:47,376 42957 operations dropped so far.
```

I restarted the datastax-agent but still I could not find any error's in the log file below is the agent.log file

Startup log:

```
 Starting DataStax agent monitor datastax_agent_monitor[  OK  ]
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.eclipse.jetty.util.log).
    log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
    log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
     INFO [main] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,191 Loading conf files: /var/lib/datastax-agent/conf/address.yaml
     INFO [main] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,260 Java vendor/version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.7.0_25
     INFO [main] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,261 Waiting for the config from OpsCenter
     INFO [main] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,262 Attempting to determine Cassandra's broadcast address through JMX
     INFO [main] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,264 Starting Stomp
     INFO [main] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,264 SSL communication is disabled
     INFO [main] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,264 Creating stomp connection to x.x.x.x:61620
     INFO [Initialization] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,266 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
     INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,274 Reconnecting in 0s.
     INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,280 Connected to x.x.x.x:61620
     INFO [main] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,313 Starting Jetty server: {:port 61621, :host nil, :ssl? false, :join? false}
     INFO [Jetty] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,511 Jetty server started
     INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,566 Got new config from OpsCenter: {:kerberos_use_keytab true, :rollups300_ttl 2419200, :kerberos_use_ticket_cache true, :rollups60_ttl 604800, :thrift_port 9160, :ec2_metadata_api_host "x.x.x.x", :metrics_enabled 1, :rollups7200_ttl 31536000, :thrift_ssl_truststore nil, :metrics_ignored_column_families "", :cassandra_log_location "/var/log/cassandra/system.log", :thrift_rpc_interface "x.x.x.x", :thrift_ssl_truststore_password nil, :jmx_port 7199, :provisioning 0, :use_ssl 0, :kerberos_debug false, :rollups86400_ttl -1, :api_port "61621", :storage_keyspace "OpsCenter", :kerberos_renew_tgt true, :metrics_ignored_solr_cores "", :thrift_ssl_truststore_type "JKS", :metrics_ignored_keyspaces "system, system_traces, system_auth, dse_auth, OpsCenter", :rollup_subscriptions [], :cassandra_install_location ""}
     INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,567 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
     INFO [Initialization] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,633 Using x.x.x.x as the cassandra broadcast address
     INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,662 Starting up agent collection.
     INFO [Initialization] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,714 agent RPC address is  x.x.x.x
     INFO [Initialization] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,715 agent RPC broadcast address is  x.x.x.x
     INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,721 Starting OS metric collectors (Linux)
     INFO [Initialization] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,723 Clearing ssl.truststore
     INFO [Initialization] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,723 Clearing ssl.truststore.password
     INFO [Initialization] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,723 Setting ssl.store.type to JKS
     INFO [Initialization] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,728 Clearing kerberos.service.principal.name
     INFO [Initialization] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,728 Clearing kerberos.principal
     INFO [Initialization] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,728 Setting kerberos.useTicketCache to true
     INFO [Initialization] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,728 Clearing kerberos.ticketCache
     INFO [Initialization] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,729 Setting kerberos.useKeyTab to true
     INFO [Initialization] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,729 Clearing kerberos.keyTab
     INFO [Initialization] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,729 Setting kerberos.renewTGT to true
     INFO [Initialization] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,729 Setting kerberos.debug to false
     INFO [thrift-init] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,733 Connecting to Cassandra cluster: x.x.x.x (port 9160)
     INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,737 Starting Cassandra JMX metric collectors
     INFO [thrift-init] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,749 Downed Host Retry service started with queue size -1 and retry delay 10s
     INFO [StompConnection receiver] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,755 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
     INFO [thrift-init] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,757 Registering JMX me.prettyprint.cassandra.service_Agent Cluster:ServiceType=hector,MonitorType=hector
     INFO [pdp-loader] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,834 in execute with client org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client@67cf1438
     INFO [thrift-init] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,836 Connected to Cassandra cluster: /Test
     INFO [pdp-loader] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,844 Attempting to load stored metric values.
     INFO [thrift-init] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,841 in execute with client org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client@67cf1438
     INFO [thrift-init] 2013-11-27 01:37:45,845 Using partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
     INFO [jmx-metrics-1] 2013-11-27 01:37:50,748 New JMX connection (127.0.0.1:7199)
     INFO [qtp131393312-25] 2013-11-27 01:38:59,902 HTTP: :get /os-metric/disk-space {} - 200
     INFO [qtp131393312-24] 2013-11-27 01:39:04,468 HTTP: :get /os-metric/disk-space {} - 200

WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-27 01:42:45,841 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-27 01:42:45,842 1 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-27 01:42:45,842 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-27 01:42:45,842 2 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-27 01:42:45,843 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-27 01:42:45,843 3 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-27 01:42:45,843 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-27 01:42:45,843 4 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-27 01:42:45,843 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-27 01:42:45,843 5 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-27 01:42:45,844 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-27 01:42:45,844 6 operations dropped so far.
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-27 01:42:45,844 Thrift operation queue is full, discarding thrift operation
 WARN [rollup-snapshot] 2013-11-27 01:42:45,844 7 operations dropped so far.
```

Thrift is running:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:7199                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      498        21333533   15520/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9160                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      498        21334831   15520/java
```

Cassandra nodes are up and running.

Comment: The first log you included is actually the agent log as well. That is indicating that the agent is having trouble writing data to the cluster via thrift, but it shouldn't affect the list of keyspaces. Can you look for errors in the OpsCenter log and include them here? Also it would be useful to send the output from 'curl http://<opsc_url>:<port>/<cluster_name>/keyspaces'

Comment: I updated the logs and strange is that now I can see the keyspaces but every time I restart my browser it is taking long time and what about those WARN?

Comment: The WARN messages mean that the agent can't connect to cassandra via thrift. Is your cassandra node up and is thrift running? The other stack trace you pasted should be fixed in a later version of OpsCenter. Can you upgrade to 3.2.2 or 4.0.1?

Comment: I upgraded to 4.0.1 but still same warnings.

Comment: I added these to address.yaml file thrift_max_conns: 100
async_pool_size: 100. Still the same error

Comment: The warnings about thrift? Those warnings are not related to the version of OpsCenter, those simply indicate that the agent can not connect to the local cassandra node via thrift. Assuming the thrift server is started and configured correctly, I would need to see more of the agent log to know what is wrong. There should be actual connection errors in the log as well.

Comment: I added the log from start up please look into it. I could not find any error's in my log

Comment: Thrift is running and cassandra is up and running.

Comment: Hmm, if thrift is running and the agent is able to connect successfully then it is just unable to keep up with the number of metrics it is collecting. The most likely candidates are either that you have a very large number of column families or your cluster is under a fair amount of load and responding very slowly.

Comment: I had very large number of column families i.e ~ greater than 600. Tha'ts the reason I aaded the max_thrift_conns to 100. Is this will cause any problem to my cassandra cluster if I run repair service with opscenter? is there any work around for this?

Comment: It shouldn't cause any problems with running repair service, except that it may take repair service longer to complete. You can control which keyspaces and column families metrics are collected for. See http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/4.0/webhelp/index.html#opsc/configure/../../opsc/configure/../../opsc/configure/opscExcludingKeyspaces_c.html.

Comment: I tried to run the repair service but am getting the ERROR: Repair service cannot complete without adversely affecting the cluster. Required parallel repairs: 47.0, Max parallel repairs: 1, Shutting down repair service. I increased the number of day to 20 and parallel copies to 10 but still the same error. What is the max value for parallel copies and what happens if I increase the number of days more than gc_grace_period. Increased the days based on this article https://support.datastax.com/entries/29979053-Repair-Service-Wont-Start-Cant-Allocate-Parallel-Repair-Threads-

Comment: you should open another question regarding that issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue in this case was related to the number of column families created in the cluster. A large number of column families can slow down fetching the list of keyspaces and column families as well as back up metric insertion. You can configure which column families have metrics collected. See:

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/4.0/webhelp/index.html#opsc/configure/../../opsc/configure/../../opsc/configure/opscExcludingKeyspaces_c.html

If you don't want to disable monitoring on clusters with a large number of column families, there are a few settings you can tweak in the agent config.

```
thrift_max_conns - the max number of concurrent connections to make to the local node
asysnc_pool_size - the size of the threadpool pulling from a queue of inserts and inserting in to cassandra
async_queue_size - the size of the queue of inserts to send to cassandra, if the queue fills up additional operations will be dropped
```

Comment: I don't want to exclude any of my keyspaces from monitoring. is there any way to do that?

Comment: I've edited my answer with the appropriate settings to tweak.

Comment: Are these config options still applicable with DSE 4.6.1, OpsC 5.1.0? They're not documented here: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.1/opsc/configure/agentAddressConfiguration.html. I'm seeing a lot of the following message in my nodes' agent.log: "Cassandra operation queue is full, discarding cassandra operation". I have 400+ tables in my keyspace